# Python: find the highest number of time overlap

Tags: python, overlap, period

I have a nested list:

```
[['2012 Mar 03 23:39:46', '2012 Mar 03 23:39:58'], ['2012 Mar 03 23:32:46', '2012 Mar 03 23:32:46'], ['2012 Mar 03 23:12:19', '2012 Mar 03 23:12:19'], ['2012 Mar 03 23:06:50', '2012 Mar 03 23:08:03'], ['2012 Mar 03 22:57:28', '2012 Mar 03 22:57:28'], ['2012 Mar 03 22:47:00', '2012 Mar 03 22:47:00'], ['2012 Mar 03 22:45:45', '2012 Mar 03 22:45:45'], ['2012 Mar 03 22:37:41', '2012 Mar 03 22:37:41'], ['2012 Mar 03 22:35:15', '2012 Mar 03 22:35:15'], ...]
```

I would like to find the highest number when these time ranges overlap each other (for example when there are 3 time periods that overlap each other, I would like to get "3"). This list is sorted in descending order.

I wrote this code:

```
counter=list()
for i in range(len(sorted_times)):
    j=i
    while j < len(sorted_times):
        temp_counter=0
        if sorted_times[i][0] <= sorted_times[j][1]:
            temp_counter +=1
            j +=1
        else:
            counter.append(temp_counter)
            break
```

But the list `counter` is only filled with `0`. I solved this problem before by using the `pandas` and `numpy` libraries, and I know that there should be 2 time ranges that are overlapping. This time I would like to do this using only built-in python libraries (except the time or datetime libraries).

I don't know what is wrong with this code. It should at least return a list full of `1`s, if there are no overlapping time periods.

I hope I explained my problem clearly enough. It's my first post here, so I'm sorry in advance if something is missing here.

**EDIT**

As Tim Castelijns sugested, this is my list with timestamps (float numbers) which I also tried:

```
[[1330814386.0, 1330814398.0], [1330813966.0, 1330813966.0], [1330812739.0, 1330812739.0], [1330812410.0, 1330812483.0], [1330811848.0, 1330811848.0], [1330811220.0, 1330811220.0], [1330811145.0, 1330811145.0], [1330810661.0, 1330810661.0], [1330810515.0, 1330810515.0], [1330810361.0, 1330810417.0], [1330809037.0, 1330809037.0], [1330808213.0, 1330808213.0], [1330807897.0, 1330807897.0],
```

And I found out why my code didn't work properly - I should wrote:

```
temp_counter=0
while j < len(sorted_times):
```

instead of:

```
while j < len(sorted_times):
    temp_counter=0
```

Stupid mistake, which I couldn't see for one day :(

Unfortunately, I still didn't get the same answer as using `pandas`. When I work with bigger data sample (over 3000) using `pandas` I get the number `9` as the answer and using built-in libraries I get `5`. Is there any difference between using `time.strftime()` or not converted *timestamps in seconds* and using `pandas.to_datetime(df.timestamp, unit='s')`? I know that the time zone can be different, but it shouldn't be a problem in this case.

Comment: You're comparing strings, not dates

Comment: I made it also using timestamps in seconds and I got the same result.

Comment: Please show that attempt :-) With the code you show us now it's pretty obvious why it doesn't work